# iCloud Why Are Some Album Tracks Uploaded Instead of Matched

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

I know that iTunes Match is still in its infancy, but I'm having a weird occurrence. Most of my tracks are ripped from my CD collection.

Albums that were all ripped in one batch, some of the tracks show up as matched, while others had to be "uploaded." See the example below:

[image: Houses of Holy Uploaded versus Matched]

Any ideas?

Comment: Given that the detailled matching criteria are only known by Apple you may not get a conclusive answer.

Comment: I'm hoping it's something that they'll continue to revise.
I'm wondering if re-ripping the discs at 256 kbps will help at all. It would at least give me consistent bitrates across an entire album.

Comment: I'm having this same problem, and I've read reports around the web of others too. I even tried turning Match off on all of my devices and starting over — didn't help. I'm kind of holding out for an iTunes software update soon to address this, but I don't know if that is likely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you notice in your screenshot, the files that were uploaded were ripped at 128kbps. This causes enough audio artifacts in the file to throw the acoustic fingerprinting that was used when iTunes Match first launched. It has since been improved and issues like this with lower bit rate files are now much less common.